# Hyphenation with Gentium Plus won't work on Windows

Tags: fonts, hyphenation, polyglossia, windows

LaTeX won't hyphenate a word
even though instructions were provided in
polyglossia's \pghyphenation. Any ideas?

I'm using MiKTeX LuaLaTeX.

UPDATE: It works as expected if I set the font to GentiumPlus-Regular,
as per David Carlisle's comment.

And a bonus question: is there a way to force a new line in cases where text would go over the text margin? Ie. to make the line shorter instead of longer than the rest.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{slovenian}
\setromanfont{Gentium Plus}

\pghyphenation{slovenian}{za-hod-no-juž-no-slo-van-ski}

\begin{document}
    Testiranje še malo in zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 
    zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski zahodnojužnoslovanski 

    \parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}zahodnojužnoslovanski}
    
    \showhyphens{zahodnojužnoslovanski}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

(Actual) log:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.1 (MiKTeX 22.10) (format=lualatex 2022.10.17)  18 OCT 2022 11:08
 restricted system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**polyglossia_hyphenation_test.tex
(./polyglossia_hyphenation_test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-10-03.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2022-10-03.
lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/MiKT
eX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'
.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local
/MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen137
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty"
Package: polyglossia 2022/07/18 v1.57 Modern multilingual typesetting with XeLa
TeX and LuaLaTeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count191
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty"
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count192
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2022-09-28 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2022-09-28 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: xparse 2022-06-22 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty"
Package: fontspec-luatex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen138
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen140

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg")))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2022-06-22 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty"
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty"
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count271
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable12
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable13
)
Lua module: polyglossia 2013/05/11 1.3 Polyglossia
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.lde"
Package: gloss-latex 2021/07/10 vv1.53 polyglossia: module for default language

The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/DefineCommandsCmd}  =>  {use_none:n}.
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is latex.
Package polyglossia Info: Setting LuaTeX font renderer to Harfbuzz.
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-slovenian.ldf"
File: gloss-slovenian.ldf polyglossia: module for slovenian
The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/DefineCommandsCmd}  =>  {use_none:n}
>  {slovenian/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {slovenian/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {slovenian/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {slovenian/language}  =>  {Slovenian}
>  {slovenian/langtag}  =>  {SLV}
>  {slovenian/bcp47}  =>  {sl}
>  {slovenian/hyphennames}  =>  {slovenian,slovene}
>  {slovenian/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {slovenian/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,2}
>  {slovenian/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {slovenian/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {slovenian/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {slovenian/envname}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {slovenian/babelname}  =>  {slovene}
>  {slovenian/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {slovenian/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {slovenian/DefineCommandsCmd}  =>  {xpg_define_language_commands:e}.
Module polyglossia Info: Language data for slovenian
(polyglossia)            lefthyphenmin  2
(polyglossia)            hyphenation    
(polyglossia)            synonyms   slovene
(polyglossia)            righthyphenmin 2
(polyglossia)            loader loadhyph-sl.tex
(polyglossia)            patterns   hyph-sl.pat.txt on input line 10
Module polyglossia Info: Language slovenian was not yet loaded; created with id 
2 on input line 10
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is slovenian.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/MiK
TeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'GentiumPlus(0)' created for font 'Gentium
(fontspec)             Plus' with options [Renderer=Harfbuzz,Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tli
g;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+tli
g;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+t
lig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/B:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+t
lig;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+t
lig;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/I:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+t
lig;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+
tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"GentiumPlus/BI:mode=harf;script=latn;language=dflt;+
tlig;+smcp;"

LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 7.

(./polyglossia_hyphenation_test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 2.
)
\openout1 = polyglossia_hyphenation_test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 9
.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n on input line 9.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n on inpu
t line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/it on input line 9
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/b/n on input line 9.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/b/n on inpu
t line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/GentiumPlus(0)/b/it on input line 
9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 9.
The property list \__xpg_alias contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {latex/target}  =>  {latex}
>  {slovenian/target}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {sl/target}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {slovene/target}  =>  {slovenian}.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 9.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 9.

Overfull \hbox (67.59819pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
[]\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 Te-stiranje še ma-lo in za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnoju
žnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (64.83647pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--21
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski za-
hodnojužnoslovanski za-hodnojužnoslovanski
 []


Overfull \hbox (13.36136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-
 []


Overfull \hbox (95.3313pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22
\TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 hodnojužnoslovanski 
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 22.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--24
[] \TU/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n/10.95 za-hodnojužnoslovanski

\hbox(8.28735+2.67334)x16383.99998, glue set 13485.89746, direction TLT []

The property list \polyglossia@langsetup contains the pairs (without outer
braces):
>  {latex/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {latex/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {latex/language}  =>  {Latex}
>  {latex/langtag}  =>  {ENG}
>  {latex/bcp47}  =>  {}
>  {latex/hyphennames}  =>  {english}
>  {latex/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {latex/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,3}
>  {latex/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {latex/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {latex/envname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/babelname}  =>  {latex}
>  {latex/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {latex/DefineCommandsCmd}  =>  {use_none:n}
>  {slovenian/script}  =>  {latin}
>  {slovenian/lcscript}  =>  {latin}
>  {slovenian/scripttag}  =>  {}
>  {slovenian/language}  =>  {Slovenian}
>  {slovenian/langtag}  =>  {SLV}
>  {slovenian/bcp47}  =>  {sl}
>  {slovenian/hyphennames}  =>  {slovenian,slovene}
>  {slovenian/direction}  =>  {LR}
>  {slovenian/hyphenmins}  =>  {2,2}
>  {slovenian/frenchspacing}  =>  {false}
>  {slovenian/indentfirst}  =>  {false}
>  {slovenian/fontsetup}  =>  {true}
>  {slovenian/envname}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {slovenian/babelname}  =>  {slovene}
>  {slovenian/localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {slovenian/Localnumeral}  =>  {polyglossia@C@localnumeral}
>  {slovenian/DefineCommandsCmd}  =>  {xpg_define_language_commands:e}.
The property list \__xpg_alias contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {latex/target}  =>  {latex}
>  {slovenian/target}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {sl/target}  =>  {slovenian}
>  {slovene/target}  =>  {slovenian}.
[1

{C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(./polyglossia_hyphenation_test.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 2.
))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 4435 strings out of 477352
 125038,662416 words of node,token memory allocated
 787 words of node memory still in use:
   5 hlist, 2 vlist, 1 rule, 1 disc, 1 local_par, 5 glue, 3 kern, 1 penalty, 44 
glyph, 7 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 7 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:43,3:24,4:2,5:22,6:6,7:3092,8:1,9:48,10:1,11:234
 25495 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 39 fonts using 17692175 bytes
 86i,5n,86p,311b,229s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/gentiumplus-r.ttf>
Output written on polyglossia_hyphenation_test.pdf (1 page, 32830 bytes).

PDF statistics: 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE3Sb.png) from lualatex (and same from xelatex)

Comment: show the log file you get from the above

Comment: @DavidCarlisle question updated.

Comment: that's the console not the log but looks OK, do you have (in the log) `Package: polyglossia 2022/07/18 v1.57 Modern multilingual typesetting with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX` (I have texlive not miktex but it shouldn't make any difference)

Comment: ah but I have /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/gentium-tug/GentiumPlus-Regular.ttf ie Gentium from the tex system you have C:/Users/msusnik/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/gentiumplus-r.ttf so a system installed one, that is the only difference I see, what happens if you set the font to `GentiumPlus-Regular.ttf ` ie use the filename not internal font name?

Comment: If I ask `\showhyphens{zahodnojužnoslovanski}`, with or without the `\pghyphenation` instruction, I get `za-ho-dno-juž-no-slo-van-ski`. What do you get? You'll see the result in the log file. This with XeLaTeX; with LuaLaTeX only `za-hodnojužnoslovanski`. Something fishy is happening.

Comment: It seems a specific problem with Gentium Plus; with other fonts the issue does not show up.

Comment: @egreg are you picking up the texlive gentium or  system one?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess the system one has precedence. And, indeed, if I load the TeX Live one, hyphenation is as expected.

Comment: It seems I had some old version of Gentium Plus in the AppData Fonts folder that was taking precedence over the newer fonts in Windows' Fonts folder and the fonts from MiKTeX. Deleting those fixed it, now MikTeX's font is taking precedence, which is probably okay. The hyphenation is now working properly. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the system provided Gentium Plus font has some “hidden features”. I have no access to Windows, but a similar problem happens on macOS.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{slovenian}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}zahodnojužnoslovanski}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The log file shows that we're loading `/Library/Fonts/gentium-tug/GentiumPlus-R.ttf`

If I compile with XeLaTeX, instead, I get

[image]

The loaded font is, for mysterious reasons, `/Library/Fonts/gentium-tug/GentiumPlus-I.ttf`

OK, now I realize that I didn't update my Library, so I'll do it now.

Hurray! The faulty fonts with `-R` and `-I` are gone and the output is the same with LuaLaTeX as with XeLaTeX, namely

[image]